# Order of element in quotient group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be the free $\mathbf{Z}$-module of rank $3$ with basis $x_1, x_2, x_3$. Consider the submodules $$ B = \langle x_1 + x_2 + 4x_3, 2x_1-x_2-2x_3 \rangle \text{ and } C = \langle 2x_1+x_2-50x_3, 4x_1+5x_2+60x_3 \rangle.$$ Find the order of $x_1+2x_3+B \in A/B$ and the order of $32x_1+31x_2+C \in A/C$.

I know that B and C are submodules of A and they have bases that somehow correlate. But I don't know how this $A/B$ looks like to find order of elements in it. Please give me some ideas how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elements of $A/B$ are equivalence classes of elements of $A$ where $t + B = 0 + B$ if and only if $t \in B$. The order of $x_1 + 2x_3 + B$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ (if it exists) such that

$$ n(x_1 + 2x_3) + B = 0 + B $$

which is equivalent to

$$ n(x_1 + 2x_3) \in B $$

which is equivalent to there exists $a, b \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that

$$ n(x_1 + 2x_3) = a(x_1 +x_2 + 4x_3) + b(2x_1 - x_2 - 2x_3). $$

If no such $n$ exists then the order is infinite. If you divide by $n$ on both sides you will get an equation over $\mathbf{Q}$ which can be solved using usual linear algebra. If you don't get a solution then you can conclude that the order is infinite. If you do get a solution, reduce the fractions and clear denominators to get the solution in $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. I've found out that first element has n=+inf, and from the second one I got that n can be anything in Z, so I choosed minimal, i.e. n=1